# In Flutter, is it possible to draw on a background image and save it at the same size and resolution?

Tags: flutter, image, buffer, drawing

It seems that there is no easy way to draw something onto a background image and save it with original size and resolution in Flutter.  Flutter doesn't support double buffer so we can't draw directly onto an image.  It has `toImage(pixelRatio: dpr)` or `PictureRecorder` but the image acquired from both is limited to widget/screen size, not the size of the original image size.

Does anyone know a package that can draw directly onto an image in Flutter?